# Pure functions with a connection to a system

Tags: object-oriented, functions

What's a good place to put pure functions that have connections to a system?

```
public class Core {
    System system;
}

public class System {
    SubSystem subSystem;
    // subSystem.Multiply(a, b);
}

public class SubSystem {
    public float Multiply(float a, float b) { return a * b; }
}
```

In this case, the `SubSystem` has a strong connection to the `System`. The functions within the `SubSystem` are pure/stateless.

The problem: If there is no state, why bother with the instance when a static class could do the same job?

Essentially it's `Core.system.subSystem.Multiply(a, b);` over `SubSystem.Multiply(a, b);`

And, sure we can go with static classes. But what happens when you have multiple systems with multiple static subsystems spread around the project? The connection is lost, and it quickly becomes a mess.

The way I see it, there are the following options:

```
Core.system.subSystem.Multiply(a, b); // instances
SubSystem.Multiply(a, b);             // static
SystemUtils.SubSystem.Multiply(a, b); // with namespace
```

But which one is best? And is there a better way?

Comment: If subsystems are stateles why would you want to have many of them?

Comment: Sub-system may not be the correct word for it. It's all about separating functions into logical chunks that have some connection to the data that it modifies.

Comment: Whatever you prefer to call it, if it is stateless why would you want to have many of them? And nothing in your question seems to be about modifying data.

Comment: Subsystem doesn't have any reference to System, as you imply. You don't need instances for pure methods.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem: If there is no state, why bother with the instance when a static class could do the same job?

Objects can be developed using interfaces and thus mocked. Static classes cannot implement interfaces.
On a related note, objects can be passed from one method to the other, but static classes cannot.

> If there is no state, why bother with the instance when a static class could do the same job?

"no state" and "static" are not equivalent terms.

It is true that static classes and methods entail not having a state (though you can argue that static properties are still a form of state - albeit a global one).

It is not true that anything that doesn't use a state *must* therefore be static. Taking your example of a multiplication method, it's perfectly possible to create several classes which can perform this function:

- `NormalMultiplier` uses the simple `a * b` approach.
- `WolframAlphaMultiplier` asks Wolfram Alpha for the result.
- `WindowsMultiplier` relies on the Windows Calculator to find the result.

*It seems a bit silly for multiplication, but it makes more sense for e.g. getting an accurate value of pi. Your local computer won't be able to calculate pi to as many decimal digits as Wolfram Alpha can (in a reasonable timeframe); but then again, if you only need a handful of decimal digits, you don't want to have to rely on the network connection to Wolfram Alpha.*

In all three cases, the `Multiply(a,b)` method doesn't particularly requires a state; but how would you go about implementing these as static classes? You could do that, but then you make it impossible for these classes to have a *common ancestor* (e.g. `Multiplier`) or implement the same *interface* (e.g. `IMultiplier`).

This is where static classes fall apart. They are only useful in cases where there is **exactly one implementation**, never more, never less. And that's simply not always the case.
Indirectly, that also makes it impossible to mock static classes, which can be an issue when testing.

Comment: So, if you not gonna have different behaviour for `Multiply` function and you don't need to mock it for the tests(because function not depend on external resources) - you can use static method.

Comment: The "pure" attribute is probably more important than hypothetical polymorphism or mocking. Pure methods are the best type of method you can create.

Comment: @Fabio: Yes, although I disagree with yuor assertion that `you don't need to mock it for the tests(because function not depend on external resources)` Depending on external resources is irrelevant in regards to needing to test/mock something. For example, consider `MyService` which depends on `Multiplier`, with no external resources. Suppose I want to test how `MyService` behaves when it receives a _wrong_ multiplication result. I would then want to mock and inject a `WrongMultiplier` to ensure that I can test this path, and thus I need to be able to mock `Multiplier`.

Comment: @FrankHileman: Probably more important indeed, but the purity of a method and its testability/mockability are not mutually exclusive. They are two independent considerations.

Comment: @Fabio: Just to be clear: I'm aware that multiplication isn't the best example here as it's a mathematically proven operation that isn't liable to be changed at any point in the future, but the ability to test the behavior of `MyService` when its dependencies yield particular outcomes (correct result, wrong result, exception, ...) is a relevant test case, _especially_ when the dependencies themselves are open to regressions or inaccuracies.

Comment: @Flater, My point was that when I am testing `MyService` I do not care about implementation details and write tests which cover behaviour of the service. If during refactoring I decide to move some logic to the separated class and introduce as dependency - I don't need to rewrite my tests and don't need to test separated class as well, because it tested through service.

Comment: But if `MyService` in addition to the business logic going to use external resources which will slowdown tests, then I will move it behind abstraction and mock it in the tests. Or when internal logic become very complicated and amount of possible logical branches grow very large, then I will move part of the logic behind abstraction and mock it in the tests.

Comment: @Fabio: Gracefully handling error states can be considered part of the behavior. And if so, you need a way to introduce error states, which is best done by mocking the dependencies. Which means the dependencies themselves need to be developed in a way that makes them mockable. This is why I advocate inherently making `Multiplier` a mockable class. Not because you _know_ you'll _need_ to mock it, but because `Multiplier` can be used in the future in other classes which do need to be tested and therefore have their dependencies mocked. Mockability is done for the benefit of _consuming_ classes.

Comment: @Flater, you are right, I am just introducing another point of view. Future services will have tests covered whole logic and after "ugly" implementation I would see that `Multiplier` class can be used here, I will introduce it as dependency and run tests again. `Multiplier` class is implementation details, I don't want change my tests if I decide to use `Sum` class in the loop instead of `Multiplier`. Error handling usually can be captured and handled gracefully on the highest level possible of your application. Error are exceptions - exceptional behaviour shouldn't be part of internal logic.